# How to handle bra-ket in logarithm?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, linear-algebra, information

$
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left< #1 \right|}
$Say the following two equations:

$$ S = - k_B \text{Tr} (\rho \ln \rho) $$
$$ \rho = \sum _\epsilon \ket{\epsilon} \frac{\chi (\epsilon)}{w(E)} \bra{\epsilon} $$

where $\chi, w$ are some functions, and variables $\epsilon, E$ are independent. Now my textbook says

$$ S = - k_B \text{Tr} \left( \ket{\epsilon} \frac{\chi (\epsilon)}{w(E)} \ln \left( \frac{\chi (\epsilon)}{w(E)} \right) \bra{\epsilon} \right) $$

but I don't understand how to get this equation. Could anyone tell me the process?

My textbook: ["*Perspectives on Statistical Thermodynamics*"](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=nSzrAQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=ja&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=%22Using%20the%20canonical%20formalism%22&f=false) (The second and the third equations are written in p.262 though the page can't be previewed on GoogleBooks.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Note that your density matrix $\rho$ is already diagonalized. So, $ \ln (\rho)$ is simply taking log of each diagonal element.

Comment: Thank you. Your hint has totally solved my question. However, how can I prove the theorem `log(rho) is simply taking log of each diagonal element`? This fact is referred to in many websites (e.g. [Logarithm of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Calculating_the_logarithm_of_a_diagonalizable_matrix)) but I can't find the proof.

Comment: @ynn I finally succeeded to prove the theorem, using the log(matrix) definition and the fact that $A - E$ is diagonal if $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: @ynn If you have turned this hint into a nontrivial solution to your problem, you might consider writing a more complete answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: @rob Actually I considered that but didn't carry that out since it seemed troublesome (so I left some more hints for future readers). However, I think your attitude are right. So I've just added the complete answer to my question. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left< #1 \right|}
$For the future readers, I would like to prove the theorem

> If $D$ is a diagonal matrix, $\ln (D)$ is simply taking log of each diagonal element $D_i$.

At first, logarithm of a matrix is defined as this, where $E$ is an identity matrix (which often denoted as $I$).

$$ \ln (A) \equiv \sum _{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} (-1)^{k-1} (A - E)^k $$

This definition is natural since this form is completely the same as the Taylor expansion of $\ln (x)$ around $x = 1$.

Now, let $D$ be a diagonal matrix. Then we can transcribe $D$ as

$$ D = \sum _i D_i \ket{i} \bra{i} $$

, where $\{D_i\}$ are the diagonal elements and $\{\ket{i}\}$ are the base ket vectors of diagonalization. This decomposition is not strange (if you don't understand, say the simplest case where $\ket{i} = {}^t(1\ \ 0)$ and you'll understand).

In addition, the next theorem is trivial.

$$ D\ \text{is diagonal.}\ \ \Leftrightarrow\ \ D - E\ \text{is diagonal.}$$

Using these formulae, we can prove the theorem as below.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln (D) &=& \sum _{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} (-1)^{k-1} (D - E)^k \\
&=& \sum _{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} (-1)^{k-1} \left( \sum _i (D_i - E_i) \ket{i} \bra{i} \right)^k \\
&=& \sum _{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} (-1)^{k-1} \sum _i ((D_i - E_i) \ket{i} \bra{i})^k\ \ \ (\because \left< i | j \right> = \delta _{ij}) \\
&=& \sum _{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} (-1)^{k-1} \sum _i (D_i - E_i)^k \ket{i} \bra{i}\ \ \ (\because \ket{i} \bra{i} \ket{i} \bra{i} \cdots \ket{i} \bra{i} = \ket{i} \bra{i}) \\
&=& \sum _{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} (-1)^{k-1} \sum _i (D_i - 1)^k \ket{i} \bra{i} \\
&=& \sum _i \left( \sum _{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{k} (-1)^{k-1} (D_i - 1)^k \right) \ket{i} \bra{i} \\
&=& \sum _i \ln (D_i) \ket{i} \bra{i}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

This theorem instantly (and generally) solve my question.